# Which of these two JavaScript patterns is better to instantiate an object?

Tags: javascript

1. Are there any advantages to either of the following patterns or are they the exact same thing, but one is simply using `if else` shorthand?

   This

   ```
   if ((typeof ShopScript) === 'undefined') { ShopScript = {}; }
   ```

   or this?

   ```
   window.ShopScript = window.ShopScript || {};
   ```
2. I am curious about the `window.ShopScript`...  Is the `ShopScript` object attached to the window in either case (is anything else reasonable even possible)?
3. Are these such common or known patterns such that there is nomenclature to refer to them?  Ie, if I was to try and rephrase the very title question of this post as "What is the difference between pattern A and B," what would A and B .. be?

Comment: No, testing for being undefined is not the same as testing for falsyness.

Comment: `window.ShopScript = window.ShopScript || {};` is called the default-pattern

Comment: `window.ShopScript = window.ShopScript !== undefined? window.ShopScript: {};` this is called Ternary operator.

Comment: Since testing for `falsy` is different from testing for `undefined`, in regards to instantiating an object which will contain all page scripts, is there a foreseeable advantage to using `window.ShopScript = window.ShopScript !== undefined? window.ShopScript: {};` over just testing for falsy?

Comment: Nevermind, and thank you, @Ryan already answered my tertiary question in the comments below his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet doesn’t declare `ShopScript`, which isn’t a good thing. If you’re in the global scope, you can do that using `var`:

```
if (typeof ShopScript === 'undefined') {
    var ShopScript = {};
}
```

but since `var` doesn’t have block scope (that’s the whole point of using it here), you don’t need to use `typeof` to check for undefinedness anymore:

```
var ShopScript;

if (ShopScript === undefined) {
    ShopScript = {};
}
```

If you’re not in the global scope, then you’ll need to reference the global object somehow to add a property to it (`window`, for example, in browsers):

```
if (typeof ShopScript === 'undefined') {
    window.ShopScript = {};
}
```

but at that point you may as well just use it for the check; there’s really not much difference here:

```
if (window.ShopScript === undefined) {
    window.ShopScript = {};
}
```

That’s also how you get to the second snippet using `||`, which is the same* except tests if `window.ShopScript` is falsy instead of if it’s specifically `undefined`. For the case of adding a global “namespace” object, this rarely matters.

And to answer (2), yes, assigning to an undeclared variable outside of strict mode will put it on the global object. In strict mode, it throws an error, and you should be using strict mode.

<sub>* It also reassigns `ShopScript` unconditionally, which only has visible effects if `ShopScript` was defined as a property with a custom descriptor. This case, too, rarely matters.</sub>

Comment: So if I am not bothered by worse readability, I can go with the Ternary/shothand, right?   Also, since testing for `falsy` is different from testing for `undefined`, in regards to instantiating an object which will contain all page scripts, do you know of a foreseeable advantage to using `window.ShopScript = window.ShopScript !== undefined? window.ShopScript: {};` over just testing for `falsy`?

Comment: @AndreBulatov: `window.ShopScript = window.ShopScript || {};` is standard and fine, yes. You can also do `var ShopScript = ShopScript || {};` in the global scope.